# Libevent - IPv6 connected

Tags: c, libevent

Tell me please, i'm trying to figure out if Liebevent can use ipiv6.
At the moment I am reading about Bufferevents:concepts and basics: [Bufferevents:concepts and basics](https://www.seul.org/%7Enickm/libevent-book/Ref6_bufferevent.html)

There says that:

> If the bufferevent’s socket is not yet connected, you can launch a new
> connection.
>
> bufferevent_socket_connect(struct bufferevent *bev,struct **sockaddr**
> *address, int addrlen);
>
> The address and addrlen arguments are as for the standard call
> connect().

I'm confused by the structure - sockaddr, since she has no fields for ip v6.

And so I can't figure out how to enter information about IPv6?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [libevent evhttp and ipv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14837107/libevent-evhttp-and-ipv6)

Comment: @Nick ODell, Unfortunately no.

Comment: Sounds like you need a good introduction to socket programming like W. Richard Stevens' Unix Network Programming or Beej's Guide.

Comment: You need a struct sockaddr_in6.  Note that sockaddr has to be specialized for the specific protocol used.

Comment: @stark, yes I know that for IPv6 the structure is used sockaddr_in6, but the bufferevent_socket_connect function accepts a "sockaddr" structure as input.

Comment: @Shawn, no, I don’t need it.

Comment: @stark, I think I figured out bufferevent_socket_connect (), just like WSAConnect () takes a structure and sockaddr_in and sockaddr_in6 are cast to a pointer to a structure (sockaddr *)

Comment: If you don't understand how sockaddr structs work... Yes, you do.